# editing the output after getting the result

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a program which takes 2 digits, X,Y as input and generates a 2-dimensional array. The element value in the i-th row and j-th column of the array should be i*j.
Note: i=0,1.., X-1; j=0,1,¡­Y-1.

## Example

Suppose the following inputs are given to the program:
3,5
Then, the output of the program should be:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]

## My program:

```
x=int(raw_input())
y=int(raw_input())

l=[]

for i in range(x):    

   for j in range(y):
         l.append((i*j))
print l
```

## My output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I am not able to get final touch like:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

Could anyone kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(raw_input())
y = int(raw_input())

l=[]
for i in range(x):   
    inner_list = []
    for j in range(y):
        inner_list.append((i*j))
    l.append(inner_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(raw_input())
y = int(raw_input())

l = []
```

Info on lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
for i in range(x):
    l.append([]) # Add a empty nested list

    for j in range(y):
        l[-1].append(i * j) # append to index of nested empty list
```

INPUT: INT(3,5)

OUTPUT: l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]

**List Comprehension:**

If you're looking for a shorter script you could try list comprehension in place of your for loop.

Ex:

```
l = [[j * i for j in range(y)]for i in range(x)]
```

INPUT INT(3,5)

OUTPUT: l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]